# Modifying audio of a movie file (mp4, mkv)

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, video, web-applications

I'm trying to build a web app with node and vanilla javascript right now to change user inputted mp4 and mkv file audio client side and am unsure if it is even possible? What API should I use to do modify the volume for instance of a movie file and then return back to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using the WASM (web assembly) [version of FFMPEG](https://ffmpegwasm.netlify.app/)

Comment: Please do not post links in the answer

Comment: Ill check that out, thank you